# How can I ask "which one is your favorite/do you like more"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, sentence-structure

I want to ask "which one is your favorite?", like between A and B, which one do you like more.
Can I say "哪一个你最喜欢?" or "哪个你更喜欢?"? Is there a better way to ask? At this point I feel like I'm just throwing words together trying to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in English:

Say "哪一个你最喜欢?/ 你最喜欢哪一个?" (which one you like the most) when you are choosing between three or more items

or

Say "哪一个你更喜欢?/ 你更喜欢哪一个" (which one you like better). when you are choosing between two items